# Distribution of $X$ if $(X,Y)$ jointly is a 2D normal distribution, given $Y$ in the range of $[a,b]$.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

If $(X,Y)$ follows a 2D normal distribution, given $Y$ in the range of $[a,b]$, is there any closed form of the distribution of $X$?

A possible way should be to get the conditional distributions of $X$ by sampling $Y$ in the range of $[a,b]$, and add all these distributions together.

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ has a (possibly degenerate) bivariate normal distribution and if the range of $Y$ is bounded, then $Y$ must be degenerate (i.e., $Y$ is a constant random variable). Are you considering a conditional distribution of $(X,Y)$ given $Y\in[a,b]$?

Comment: I'm thinking about the distribution of $X$ given $Y∈[a,b]$. Basically, I need to evaluate this integration:
$∫ab P(X|Y=y) P(Y=y) dy$
The conditional distribution of P(X|Y=y) should be a normal distribution, thus I assume the integration also gives me a normal distribution.